# Count redundant for each value in a column in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sql-insert

If I have the following table  in a SQL Server 2019 database as follows:

```
|id   | name   | count  |
+-----+--------+--------+
| 1   | rose   |   1    |
| 2   | peter  |   1    |
| 3   | ann    |   1    |
| 4   | rose   |   2    |
| 5   | ann    |   2    |
| 6   | ann    |   3    |
| 7   | mike   |   1    |
```

I would like to find out if an inserted name already exists in the column "name" and how many times and right a count next to it as shown in "count" column. For example when ann was inserted the second time I put count value bext to it which is 2, and ann was inserted the third time I put 3 next to it.

How to do that using SQL?

Thank you

Comment: What's the expected result when ann 2 is deleted? Should ann 3 be renumbered?

Comment: @jarlh if ann 2 is deleted count value 3 for ann should be updated yes

Comment: Then you probably need a trigger based solution. Or have a view, or computed column.

Comment: Use View, this data is not very suitable for storing in tables. And use function ROW_NUMBER () OVER (
    [PARTITION BY partition_expression, ...]
    ORDER BY sort_expression [ASC | DESC], ...
)

Sorts the data by the name column and creates exactly what you want.   https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach using the `insert ... select` syntax:

```
insert into mytable (name, cnt)
select v.name, (select count(*) + 1 from mytable t where t.name = v.name)
from (values (@name)) v(name)
```

The value to insert is given as `@name` in derived table `values()`. Then we use a subquery to count how many such names already exist in the table.

Comment: If you have the values ​​[Ann 1], [Ann 2] and [Ann 3], and you delete Ann 1, this script will insert [Ann 3]. And you will have redundant data (2x [Ann 3]). I don't think you want that.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you calculate this information when you *query* the table, rather than when you *insert* rows:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (partition by name order by id) as count
from t;
```

The value will always be correct -- even when the data is updated or rows are deleted.

Comment: yes this would be another good possibility. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

```
Select Name, Count(*) 
From Table
Group By Name
```

Comment: I tried your code but how to insert the generated counts into the "count" column. because it gives the counts in a "No column name"

Comment: @Adam, use "as",   Select Name, Count(*) as XXXXX FROM ........ now the column name is XXXX

Comment: @PavelKučera, yes thanks. that could work too, in this case the whole column will be counted and updated each time I insert or delete a value.